# Reset 2D array of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array declared with:

```
vector<int> array[10][10];
```

What would be the fastest way of clearing out any data in the array? I have tried:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

But that isn't working.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "resetting" it? And why not `vector<vector<vector<int> > >`, btw?

Comment: By resetting I mean removing any data it it might have previously held and returning it to the state it would have been in when initially declared. And I didn't use `vector<vector<vector<int> > >` because the size of the 2D array doesn't need to be changed but would be only using a vector be a better option?

Answer (score 1):

That's a 2D array of vectors. In other words, it's basically a 3D array with the 3rd dimension dynamic. If you wanted to create a dynamic 2D array, you would do it like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > array(10, vector<int>(10));
```

To clear:

```
array.clear();
array.resize(10, vector<int>(10));
```

If you want to stick to your array you can clear it with a loop:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        array[i][j].clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate through the 2D portion of the array, and clear each vector.  The fastest way should look something like:

```
for(unsigned int x = 0; x != 10; ++x) {
  for(unsigned int y = 0; y != 10; ++y) {
    array[x][y].resize(0);
  }
}
```